# ¿Cómo puedo pedir datos para un arreglo separados por un espacio? (Java)

Tags: java, array

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de la universidad y en uno de los ejercicios me pide que ingrese una serie de valores separados por un espacio " " y una vez que haya terminado presionando el botón "Enter", almacene dichos valores en un arreglo.
Se como introducir valores en un arreglo pero no de esta manera. Si alguien me aconseja, se le agradece.

Comment: Los lees en una variable de tipo cadena. Luego usas la función `split` para partir la cadena y obtener un arreglo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> El siguiente código podría resolver tu problema. Saludos.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);{
        
    System.out.println("Ingresa cuántos números quieras: ");
    String cadenaNum = sc.nextLine(); //Pedimos al usuario que ingrese cuantos números quiera.
    
    //El siguiente código evitará que el programa deje de funcionar en caso 
    //que el usuario ingrese más de un espacio en blanco al momento de 
    //ingresar valores.
    char c = '0';
    char []arrCadena = new char [cadenaNum.length()]; //Cadena que guardará los valores separados por un único espacio.
    
    //Ciclo que permite recorrer cada elemento del arreglo de valores con 
    //un único espacio.
    for(int i=0; i<cadenaNum.length(); i++){
        //Guardamos el último caracter obtenido de la posición "i" de la cadena.
        char a = c;
        
        //c es igual al caracter obtenido de la posición "i" de la cadena.
        c = cadenaNum.charAt(i);
        
        //Si el caracter encontrado dentro de la cadena (c) es un espacio en 
        //blanco y antes de él ya hay un espacio en blanco (a), cambia el valor 
        //de la cadena a un valor nulo y agregalo a la cadena.
        if(a==c){
            char b = '\0';
            arrCadena[i] = b;
            
        //Si no, sigue agregando valores a la cadena.
        }else{
            arrCadena[i] = c;
        }
    }
    
    String numeros = String.valueOf(arrCadena);//Palabra que contiene los valores de la cadena con valores separados por un único espacio.
    
    //Dividimos la palabra en valores que están separados por espacios en 
    //blanco y los guardamos en un arreglo de valores exactos.
    String []arrCadenaNum = numeros.trim().split(" ");
    
    //Iniciamos un nuevo arreglo de tipo entero el cual guardará todos los 
    //valores de tipo cadena de texto parseados a números enteros.
    int []arrNumeros = new int[arrCadenaNum.length];
    
    //Ciclo que permite recorrer cada elemento del arreglo con valores exactos.
    for(int i=0; i<arrNumeros.length; i++){
        //Guardamos los valores obtenidos en el arreglo de tipo entero 
        //después de haber parseado dichos valores de la cadena con valores exactos.
        arrNumeros[i] = Integer.parseInt(arrCadenaNum[i].trim());
    }
    
    System.out.println(""+Arrays.toString(arrNumeros));//Mostramos el resultado final.
    }
}
```